# Angular Typescript replace string innerHTML with span

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I'm searching for a string in the innerHTML of a div and want to set a span.  My approach doesn't work without any error. What's going wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div class="resultText" #txt></div>
```

**JS**

```
...
@ViewChild('txt') txt: ElementRef;
...
this.txt.nativeElement.innerHTML = text;
...
var query = 'test';
this.highlight(query);

highlight(query) {
      var c = this.txt.nativeElement.innerHTML;
      c.replace(new RegExp(query, "gi"), match => {
          console.log('query: ' + query);
          return '<span class="highlightText">' + match + '</span>';
      });
}
```

Comment: Instead of saying "my approach doesn't work without error", please explain your error or unexpected behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning the replaced text back to `innerHTML`

```
this.txt.nativeElement.innerHTML = c.replace(new RegExp(query, "gi"), match => {
      console.log('query: ' + query);
      return '<span class="highlightText">' + match + '</span>';
});
```